# Can I safely use a thread to call a script from a Tkinter application with subprocess.call?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

So I have a Tkinter application that I use at work.  I wrote another Tkinter application that I wanted to call from the main Tkinter application.  I know that Tkinter isn't 'thread safe', but I'm not 100% sure what that means.  Does it mean that it can 'work', but it isn't guaranteed to work as written?  Or should it just not work at all?

The reason I ask is because when I run the code below(self.thread_easy_imaging() is triggered by a filemenu option), it works just fine.  So far I haven't encountered any issues and both GUIs are operational so far as I can tell.  Is this because I'm using subprocess.call to call the script?  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this because I know you can't use thread in a Tkinter app to do something like run a function while still being able to use buttons in the GUI, but for some reason when I use a thread to call the script with subprocess.call it does it just fine.  When I wrote it, I assumed it wouldn't work, but for some odd reason it does.  Here is an example of the code I'm using:

```
def thread_easy_imaging(self): 
    thread.start_new_thread(self.start_easy_imaging, ('EASY-IMAGING-1', 0)) 
def start_easy_imaging(self, thread_name, delay): 
    time.sleep(delay) #have to have args for some reason? I just did a delay of 0 seconds so I could use the tuple.
    subprocess.call(['c:/python27/python.exe', 'EasyImaging.py'])

self.thread_easy_imaging()
```

I have only used this on a windows machine, but I'm guessing that it should work on any OS.

Edit:  The scripts don't have to interact at all, I just want to add my other GUI application into the filemenu so I can call it as a separate application.  If needed, I'll just use a Toplevel widget to recreate the application I want to call because it won't muck up the main thread at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: unrelated: don't use `thread` module directly; use `threading` module instead. You could use `subprocess.Popen` to avoid creating unnecessary threads. Why do you use `subprocess` instead of `import your_module` to run Python code?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, Well I didn't realize that importing my script would work :P Edit: Just tried it and it doesn't work..  I'll look into Popen.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very informative

Comment: Sorry, importing the other script doesn't run it for me.  I'm looking into Popen, but I'm wondering more about the constraints that Tkinter has when using threads.  Do you know if they are just unsafe or is their a safe way to do it?

Comment: what "doesn't run" mean? What do you expect to happen (output on the screen, new files saved, etc)? What happens instead? If you are using `subprocess` then it doesn't matter whether Tkinter is thread-safe or not: **it is in another process**. Unless there is a  reason; you should use `import some_module; some_module.call_some_funcs()` instead of running `some_module` as a subprocess. Tkinter **can** be used from multiple threads.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, well you asked why I wasn't importing the module and I tried that.  It says there is no module by the name of my module.  It's odd because I know it should detect it based on its location.  Sorry for the lack of information, I really appreciate your help.  I wasn't sure how to run Tkinter with multiple threads.  Someone told me it's not thread safe, and now I'm thinking they may have been specifically referring to the thread module.  I appreciate your help, I'm going to do some searching to find some good examples.  Thanks again.

Comment: you should ask about how to fix the importing error then. Create a [minimal complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a couple of modules where one module tries to import the other and fails) and post it as a new question.